# What is the db.collection.stats() command in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongoose, status

I want to check one collection's information just like the `db.collection.stats()` command in origin MongoDB

How can I do it in mongoose on schema or on model?

Comment: What exactly do you need from it? I'm not sure there's a direct .stats() cmd equivalent, but you could do something like this if taking the example from the mongoose website as an example: console.log(Cat.collection)

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem and managed to query it this way:

```
 YourModel.collection.stats(callback);
```

You basically access a `Model`'s native interface via the `collection` property (this is not the collection name, but a property in fact called `collection`). You can then use any native functions on this object.

Answer (score 1):

You can run any [arbitrary command via executeDbCommand](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/node-mongodb-native/7Xx-d2CNIrQ/j68ujBdpO0gJ) so since stats is just a database command, you can runCommand that stats() does under the hood:

db.runCommand( { collstats : collectionName } );